# period of cubic trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

Can anybody explain how you would find the period of cubic trigonometric function.

so I need to find the period of $f(x)=\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)$. So I have began the question by finding the roots of the function, which occur at $0$, $3\pi$ and $6\pi$, what next?

Comment: The period is 6opie

Comment: I would have called that a square, not a cube. Do you know the double angle formulae for $\sin 2k$ and $\cos 2k$?

Comment: Do you want a proof or just understand? If it's the latter just draw it first and you'll get the notion of it.

Comment: sorry i was supposed to put a 3

Comment: The cube only changes the amplitude of the function.